# What is the right convention for conversion of downstream error code to gRPC error code?

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

Let's say I am working in `ServiceA` which calls `ServiceB`. Now if `ServiceB` returns NotFound, AlreadyExists or InvalidArgument error codes, what should we return to the caller of `ServiceA`?

1. Based on [documentation](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/codes#Code) to gRPC error code, it looks like `Internal` is what we should return if

   > **invariants expected by the underlying system have been broken**

   I am not very sure what this bold text means, does it mean any downstream error should be returned as `Internal` error code?
2. For example, `NotFound` documentation says:

   > NotFound means some requested entity (e.g., file or directory) was not
   >   found

   Does that mean we should parse the downstream error and return `NotFound`to the caller of `ServiceA` if `ServiceB` returns `NotFound`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status code you return for the endpoint in `ServiceA` should make sense for the caller. Your business logic should dictate what status code should be returned for a downstream error. It may make sense to return pass the downstream service's code but not always.

Consider the case where you implement a `getUserDetails` endpoint which calls `getUser` from `UserService` and `getRatings` from `RatingService`.

1. If `getUser` returns *NotFound*, it makes sense to return *NotFound* to the caller as well because the user doesn't exist.
2. If `getRatings` returns *NotFound*, you can return an *Internal* error as you don't have sufficient information to return the complete response. In this case if you return *NotFound* the client may assume that the user was not found which is not the case.